# How to use QScopedPointer<QApplication>

Tags: c++, qt, qscopedpointer

I have an example that use

```
QApplication app(argc,argv);
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(r,c,&app);
```

But in my program I have

```
QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(r,c,&app); //ERROR: no matching function
```

How to use this QScopedPointer without error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
QScopedPointer<QApplication> app(createApplication(argc, argv));
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(r,c,app.data());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `app.data()`.  Though it is very unusual to create the `QApplication` on the heap...

Answer (score 1):

**hope to be useful**

```
#include <QScopedPointer>
class  target
{
 public:
 int var;
};
class logic
{
 public:
 QScopedPointer<target> variable;
 target* variable2;
};
int main()
{
 logic LogicClass;
 LogicClass.variable.reset(new target);
 LogicClass.variable->var=10;
 cout<<LogicClass.variable->var<<endl;

LogicClass.variable2 = new target;
LogicClass.variable2->var = 20;
cout<<LogicClass.variable2->var<<endl;
delete LogicClass.variable2;
return 0;
}
```